# Symfony Doctrine ManyToMany Relationship : unrecognized field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I came into a problem I can't solve for several days now.

I have a groupe table and a statistiquequestion table.

1 statistiquequestion --> several groupes
1 groupe --> several statistiquequestion

I set up a ManyToMany relationship.

Entities :

Groupe :

```
/**
 * Groupe
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="groupe")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Groupe
{
    ...
    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\PACES\StatistiqueBundle\Entity\StatistiqueQuestion", mappedBy="groupes",
 * cascade={"all"})
 */
private $statistiquesquestion;

....
}
```

StatistiqueQuestion :

```
/**
 * StatistiqueQuestion
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="statistiquequestion")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class StatistiqueQuestion
{
   ...
   /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\PACES\UserBundle\Entity\Groupe",inversedBy="statistiquesquestion" , cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="groupe_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $groupes;

....
}
```

When I try to find a StatistiqueQuestion object, I have this error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unrecognized field 'statistiquequestion_groupe.groupe_id' in where clause
```

Here's my code to get the object :

```
                    $statsQuestion[]=$em->getRepository( StatistiqueQuestion::class )->findOneBy( [ 'question'  => $colle,
                                                                                             'groupes' => $groupes
                                                                                           ] );
```

When I dump $groupes, I get an array of objects as intended.

Comment: Do you need the `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="groupe_id", referencedColumnName="id")` ? the inversedBy should link your two entities

Comment: I removed it but there's not any change.

Comment: you removed it and you have still the exact same error? `groupe_id unrecognized`?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same error

Comment: Weird thing is the field specified actually exists in SQL table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Problem was that findBy method doesn't allow to get an object with a ManyToMany Relationship.

Solution :

```
   public function getStatColleForGroupes($colle, $groupes){
    $requete = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT s
                                        FROM PACESStatistiqueBundle:StatistiqueColle s
                                        WHERE s.colle = :colle
                                        ');
    $requete->setParameters(array('colle'=>$colle));
    $resultats= $requete->getResult();


    foreach ($resultats as $resultat)
    {
        if ($groupes == $resultat->getGroupes()->toArray())
            return $resultat;
    }

    return null;
}
```

It's not optimal but it's the only solution I found to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have some clue trying

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:info
```

and

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

If the database is not in sync you probably need a doctrine:schema:update (or to generate a migration in case you're using Doctrine Migrations)

Comment: There's not any error in these commands. My database is in sync with mapping info

Comment: When I tried to dump SQL when I launch `php bin/console doctrine:schema update`. 

I get this : `ALTER TABLE statistiquequestion_groupe ADD CONSTRAINT FK_E1E778647A45358C FOREIGN KEY (groupe_id) REFERENCES groupe (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;`

So Doctrine knows this field exists. I don't find my error.

Maybe it's the findBy Method that's not woking...

Comment: The `doctrine:schema:update` is telling you there's some query to execute. Run `doctrine:schema:update --force` to execute that query.

Comment: Well you should check in the database if statistiquequestion_groupe.groupe_id exists but the error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found` tells me that you will not find it. That's why I guess it's an issue with mapping

Comment: I copy-paste table name and structure : 

Table name : statistiquequestion_groupe
1st field :  statistiquequestion_id
2nd field : groupe_id.

It does exist

Comment: Oh I see now, in the mapping of the ManyToMany you did not defined the `@ORM\JoinTable` definition (I see a JoinColumn instead). See here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional
Hope this will solve your issue